# QComboBox::showPopup() steals focus from its QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qwidget, qcombobox

In order to create a QComboBox that can filter its values list when typing in it, I attached a slot to the QComboBox's editTextChanged-event, to open its list view popup when the user starts typing. This is done like so:

```
void SearchableComboBox::slotEditing(QString in_text)
{
    this->showPopup();
}
```

Unfortunately, this immediatly steals the focus from the QLineEdit and I can't type anymore.
Calling lineEdit()->setFocus() makes no difference, and I don't want to grabKeyboard() since this creates a whole other world of pain.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Call setFocus() *after* the popup is shown.

Comment: Doesn't work, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a combobox then, more of a completion listview for a lineedit. I implemented exactly that in ruqola (KDE client for rocket chat), you can see the source code at https://lxr.kde.org/source/network/ruqola/src/widgets/common/completionlistview.cpp. Notice the little dance with the focus proxy thing:

```
      setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
      textWidget->setFocusPolicy(origPolicy);
      setFocusProxy(textWidget);
```

and the long method `slotCompletionAvailable()` for positioning the completion popup at the right place...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Focus Proxy method for this purpose. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy

With this the pop-up would relay its inputs to the lineedit.

In your case you could try something like

```
this->setFocusProxy( this->lineEdit() );
```

But maybe you should read how to use a `QCompleter`. This would provide Autocompletion while typing and is maybe also useful for you.

Comment: Not working. Your example produces the message "QComboBox () already in focus proxy chain", and setting the popup's proxy to the line edit (view()->setFocusProxy(lineEdit()) does nothing at all.

QCompleter is not a good solution for me, since search terms can produce multiple matches, and the user should receive a list of possible matches to select from.

Comment: In this case I think you are better of writing your own ComboBox. Start with QLineEdit and show a QListView as a popup. That way you'll have full control over the Focus which now gets stolen by the internal QComboBox-Popup. The other advantage is that you can easily filter the model of the list via QSortFilterProxyModel. Worth the effort imho